# difference between these three Buttons "Button button = (Button)"

Tags: java, android, android-studio

What is the difference between these three Buttons

```
Button button = (Button)
```

I mean to say what is 1st button and what is 2nd button and also what is 3rd button? I cant find the explanation on the internet, every one in the video lecture uses these three "button", **I am totally confused** with these buttons. And also

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button)
```

Why are they using `R`? Could someone just give me explanation on this line of code to better understand? please help me, **Thanks in Advance**

[image]

Comment: So I'm guessing you really need to go through [The Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) and learn the basics of the language

Comment: Post the code as text, not as image.

Comment: I think now first i have to understand JAVA first, and than i will go further, thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take a basic Java class before you dig any deeper. Here is a quick explanation of what you have asked:

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button)
```

The first `Button` is the name of the class. The second `button` is a reference to an object that you are going to get by calling `findViewById`. This reference can be anything you want. The same line could have been written as

```
Button myObjRef = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button)
```

and it would still be valid Java code. You just need to make sure that you use `myObjRef` from that point onward in your method.

The third `Button` (on the right of the `=` sign) is a type cast. This is a more complex concept and you really need to understand other things before you get to this level. Type cast tells the compiler you know what you are doing, and the object being returned by `findViewById` is of compatible type, even if not really of type `Button`.

Finally, in `R.id.button`, `R` is the name of a class. It's Android specific.

Comment: I think now first i have to understand JAVA first, and than i will go further, thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, guy, it's a root things, if you don't know how to declare variables, it will be difficult for you. My advice try to read obout java core first. 
In few words, `Button` from Capital letter is a declaration of variable type, next `button` is the name of the variable, `(button)` you can easily delete it. `R`shows on the resourses of your app.

Comment: I think now first i have to understand JAVA first, and than i will go further, thanks for answer.

Comment: Thx, for accept an answer. I can recommend you [link](https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud282) i started with it half a year ago, very good basic free cources.